# Average Time Between Multiple Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Say we have the following information:

```
**ref_no, customer, dt_created**
SO2553009, CN01806740, 2015-08-20 11:10:51.770
SO2553264, CN01806740, 2015-08-20 14:40:05.260
WW101120264, CN01806740, 2015-08-19 21:55:32.990
```

This is 3 orders for a customer and represents a typical account profile.

I need to work out the Average time between the 3* datetime fields, in days (using datediff?), because the department requesting the information wants to know the average time between orders.

If this cannot be done in SQL, I will try and mess with the information in SSRS, but the Report this is running already has multiple data-sets so I want to do most of the work in SQL to improve the user experience.

This is SQL 2008 R2, so i'm aware advanced functions like LEAD & ROW_NUMBER are not available, as I've found them in other threads asking similar questions.

- this is not a fixed number. There could be any number of orders, although the overall query will only be looking at orders with > 1 order, so no need to worry about comparing with null values.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should consider upgrading to a supported version of sql server.

Comment: It's on our roadmap for later this year/early next (up to 2016), but to be fair, SQL 2008 R2 hasn't officially hit end of life yet.

Comment: is ROW_NUMBER available in 2008 R2?  I thought it was, it seems like it was, we got stuck on that version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `lead()` for this.  Just use `max()` and `min()`:

```
select customer,
       datediff(hour, min(dt_created), max(dt_created)) / nullif(count(*) - 1, 0) as avg_diff_hours
from t
group by customer;
```

The average time between orders is the difference between the maximum and minimum divided by one less than the count.

To get days, you can divide by 24.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  T1.customer, AVG (CA.delta) as av_gap FROM 
(
SELECT T1.ref_no, T1.customer, T1.dt_created, CA.dt_created , DATEDIFF(day,T1.dt_created,CA.dt_created) as delta  FROM YourTable T1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 T2.dt_created FROM YourTable T2 WHERE T2.dt_created > T1.dt_created AND T1.customer = T2.customer ORDER BY T2.dt_created ASC ) CA
) IQ
GROUP BY IQ.T1.customer
```

you could also use JOIN if you JOIN on table1 date < Table2 date, then GROUP By includes Table1 date, and taking the MIN of table 2 date, then you could query that sub-query, or condense it via temp tables into a final result